# Using office 365 to send mails from web app

Tags: office365, exchangewebservices

I am trying to use my outlook SMTP settings in our web application to send mail to users. The mail is not reaching any of the recipients, but I also don't receive any application errors. I am configuring the mail settings in web.config as below:

```
<smtp deliveryMethod="Network" from="me@mynetwork.com">
        <network defaultCredentials="false" host="smtp.office365.com" port="587" userName="me@mynetwork.com" password="SuperSecret123(not real)" enableSsl="true"/>
      </smtp>
```

The code that sends the mail message is like this:

```
var C = new SmtpClient();
            var M = new MailMessage(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["fromemail"],to,subject,message);
            M.IsBodyHtml = true;
            C.Send(M);
```

ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["fromemail"] is the same as my from mail address. All passed variables are what they should be. If I swap out my mail settings for a test gmail account, it works. This leads me to assume that I am being spammed, but I can't confirm this because none of my test mail accounts have the messages in the spam folder, so I assume they're getting nuked on the outlook server BEFORE they're sent.

In addition, I am using a GMail account to test, so I can't really go ahead and use an Office 365 specific solution.

Answer (score 1):

Juann,

Consider using the EWS (Exchange Web Services) for sending emails. See [EWS Managed API, EWS, and web services in Exchange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd877012%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx) for more information.

Comment: How would I use EWS to send mail via GMail, or any other non-exchange provider?

Comment: There is no way. It is for Exchange only. I see Office365 tag, so it is expected that you use the hosted exchange server. Consider using BCL classes or any other third-party components instead.

Comment: I asked because when testing the application, we use a gmail account.

Answer (score 1):

In addition, for Office 365, you could consider using Mail REST APIs also.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/APi/mail-rest-operations#MessageoperationsSendmessages

Comment: I didn't mention in the question, but I use my GMail account for testing, so I can't really use anything that's not vanilla SMTP.

Answer (score 0):

The FROM mail address must be an existing address in Office 365. I often set up a SMTP server relaying to Office 365, and I can then view the errors in the logs of my local SMTP.